# How to mask data while ingesting data using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2, sqoop2, data-masking

I am extracting data using sqoop. Is there any way to mask any particular column in sqoop or modify each cell.
For example:

```
creditcardinfo
7888-3333-2222-1002
1111-2342-1235-2090
2331-2131-2222-3421
```

I want data to be like after ingestion:

```
creditcardinfo
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1002
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-2090
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-3421
```

or

```
creditcardinfo
1002
2090
3421
```

Is it possible in sqoop?I tried to find out but couldn't get much info.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do so is using a custom query for your ingestion with sqoop and in the custom query you can perform all the tranformations you want. Youcan take a look at here for reference: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports.

Comment: @mark91-You are right..That way it can be done.Is there any other way forex:java code

Comment: sqoop exentially generates a java file which compiles in a jar...you can take that java file and change it. Then you compile it into a jar and you pass that jar to sqoop..